# Question with empty title and wrong user appears

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh

I just refreshed the question list here on meta by clicking on the new "X question with new activity" link and got the following result:

[image]

After refreshing the page the old-fashioned way this emtpy question dissapeared.

Comment: Got the same thing, but with title and tags for some reason.

Comment: What browser are you using? So far, I have not noticed this, on Safari 5.1.5 running on Mac OS X 10.7.3.

Comment: For a workaround - just [fill in the blanks ;)](http://i.imgur.com/IHg6g.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the offending code - there was a few cases where answers instead of questions were making it to the realtime update.  This will be deployed shortly.

Comment: Ha! Knew it! :P But couldn't prove it ;) Geoff - you can see deleted comments can't you?  Didn't I make that comment on the OP?